# Charset encoding for CSV

Tags: java, csv, character-encoding

I have one requirement where I need to test that my CSV's content is in UTF-8 or not. I saw many threads for this but none of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

Without this info being stored in the file itself, you cannot tell for sure.

A file is a sequence of bytes. The most what you can do is test if the file is a valid UTF-8 byte sequence. The bytes in the file *might* be valid and give one `String` if you try to read it using UTF-8 encoding, and bytes *might* also be valid and give a *different* `String` if you use a different encoding, e.g. ISO 8859-1.

You should check the code or program that produces the CSV file. Just by looking at the result CSV file itself, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

CVS files could be in any format, depending on what encoding option was specified during the export from Excel: (Save Dialog, Tools Button, Web Options Item, Encoding Tab)

Default encoding is "ANSI".